# How to change BackgroundColor depending of a value in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm trying to render some bars for some stats, and i want the color of them depending of the value they have. I tried using `if` statements and `switch` but it doesn't seem to work

for the `switch` it will use the `default` value and the `if` will use the first checked value.

Sry for my english

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const Stats = ({ statName, value }) => {
  let color;

  if (value == 0) {
    color = "";
  } else if ((value) => 1 && value < 25) {
    color = "red";
  } else if (value >= 25 && value < 50) {
    color = "orange";
  } else if (value >= 50 && value < 90) {
    color = "yellow";
  } else if (value >= 90) {
    color = "green";
  }

  //   switch (value) {
  //     case value >= 1:
  //       color = "red";
  //       break;
  //     case value >= 25:
  //       color = "orange";
  //       break;
  //     case value >= 50:
  //       color = "yellow";
  //       break;
  //     default:
  //       color = "";
  //   }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{statName}</Text>
      <Text>{value}</Text>
      <View
        style={[styles.bar, { width: value * 1.5, backgroundColor: color }]}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  bar: {
    height: 20,
  },
});

export default Stats;
```

Comment: What are the values of "statName" and "value" in "Stats" component?

Comment: correct the first elseif condition 
from
else if ((value) => 1 && value < 25)

to this

else if (value >= 1 && value < 25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in the if statements: `else if ((value) => 1 && value < 25) {`, if you pay attention closely this should be: `else if (value >= 1 && value < 25) {`.

Why?
`(value) => 1` is an arrow function that always returns 1.

This should do the work:

```
(value >= 1 && value < 25)
```

But it would be better if you transform this piece of code to a function so that like this:

```
const getBackgroundColor = () => {
    let color;
    if (value === 0) {
        color = '';
    } else if (value >= 1 && value < 25) {
        color = 'red';
    } else if (value >= 25 && value < 50) {
        color = 'orange';
    } else if (value >= 50 && value < 90) {
        color = 'yellow';
    } else if (value >= 90) {
        color = 'green';
    }
    return color;
};
```

And use it like:

```
{width: value * 1.5, backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor()},
```

Answer (score 0):

The logical part of your code looks ok. Problem may be related with styling.

Can you change your styles to these instead of yours:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  bar: {
    height: 20,
    width: 20
  },
});
```

Also if top solution wont work can you verify that is **value** is a number?
By consoling it

> console.log(typeof value)

Answer (score 0):

Spelling mistake. you have to change  `(value) => 1 && value < 25)` to `(value) >= 1 && value < 25)`